# XOR decryption not working when used in script

Tags: python, reverse-engineering

I've been working on an assignment but have hit the wall at the last steps now.

The task is to automate process of connecting to server, receiving reply, processing the reply - decrypt it, encode and send it back to server.

Here is the main script, i know the data receiving part is not really proper way of doing it but it works for this task:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import socket, sys, time
from decryptmsg import decryptmsg
from cleanmsg import cleanmsg
from getkey import getkey
from xor import xorstring

#connection 
ip=<ipaddress>
port=<port>
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((ip,port))


while True:

    print "[+] START COMMUNICATION WITH SERVER..."
    data = sock.recv(8192)
    if not data:
        print "[-] ei dataa"
    print "[+] RECEIVED DATA: " + data
    data = cleanmsg(data)
    key = str(getkey(data))
    print "[+] GOT KEY: " + key
    if data != None:
        print "[!] PROCESSING DATA: " + data 
        clear_text = xorstring(data, key, decode=True)
        print clear_text
        if clear_text == None:
            print "[-] NO RESULTS FROM DECRYPTION"
            break
        else:
            print "[+] DECRYPTION SUCCESFULL, SENDING MESSAGE..." 
            sock.sendall(clear_text)
            sock.sendall("\n")
            continue
```

Here are also the function modules:

cleanmsg.py

```
import re

b64pattern = '(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}){2,}(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]=|[A-Za-z0-9+/][AQgw]+={0,2})'

def cleanmsg(data):
    if re.search(b64pattern, data):
        b64data = re.search(b64pattern,data).group(0).strip()
        return b64data
```

getkey.py

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, base64, subprocess, os

def getkey(cleaned_data):
    key = ""
    with open("secret_key.txt", 'w') as file:
        try:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(cleaned_data + b'==='))
        except:
            print "[-] B64 DECODE FAILED: "
    cmd = 'xortool -m 64 -c 20 secret_key.txt'
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.stdout.read()
    lines = iter(output.splitlines())

    for line in lines:
        #to see output of xortool
        print "[+]" + line
        if "possible" in line:
            key = next(lines, '')
            print "[!] POSSIBLE KEY DETECTED BY XORTOOL: " + key

    return key
```

xor.py

```
def xorstring(data, key="v", encode=False, decode=False):
    from itertools import izip, cycle
    import base64
    if decode:
        data = str(data)
        data = base64.b64decode(data + b'===')
    xored = ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x,y) in izip(data, cycle(key)))
    if encode:
        return base64.encodestring(xored).strip()
    return xored
```

Output from this is following:

```
[+] START COMMUNICATION WITH SERVER...
[+] RECEIVED DATA: 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

Enter the SHA-256 hash of the plaintext (in hex):

[+]The most probable key lengths:
[+]   1:   23.3%
[+]   6:   19.4%
[+]  12:   14.2%
[+]  17:   11.0%
[+]  20:   9.8%
[+]  35:   5.4%
[+]  40:   4.6%
[+]  42:   4.7%
[+]  46:   3.9%
[+]  48:   3.6%
[+]Key-length can be 3*n
[+]Key-length can be 4*n
[+]1 possible key(s) of length 1:
[!] POSSIBLE KEY DETECTED BY XORTOOL: \xa7
[+]Found 1 plaintexts with 95.0%+ printable characters
[+]See files filename-key.csv, filename-char_used-perc_printable.csv
[+] GOT KEY: \xa7
[!] PROCESSING DATA: 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
��������ꂰ�✙��ь����綫����ړ��ɒ�������۹�✅���������������ϝ����������ꏾ��қ��ԙ������ꚱ��ې��ߕ������Ꞧ��ؓज�㲶�����կ㜈��������綹����݈���������������ݏ���������������˝��ْ�������ٝ��қ�����������ݐ��̓�������ۼ��ҙ��Փ������꒫������ԉ�����������ȓ������ꏷ�������������������ѝ�朝�����������ɟ��ߓ�����������������������꓾��؎��ș������ꏷ��ԝ���������������Ɍ��ʙ�������۽��ȝ��қ�����������Џ��ș�������۷��Е����������ꓶ��˕����������ꂰ��˕�������븶������������������������㥜��������۫������ە������ꔹ��ԙ��ʙ�����徔���ș��َ��������ն�ҟ��Ӛ�������ۛ��ȓ�朝�����������؛��Ȕ���մ������ߓ���������漏���������������������Ĥ��ħ�����������
[+] DECRYPTION SUCCESFULL, SENDING MESSAGE...
[+] START COMMUNICATION WITH SERVER...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "challenge.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = sock.recv(8192)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

So the data is not properly decrypted.

However, if i take the output from above and insert it to the test script below:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from xor import xorstring

key = '\xa7'
string = 'he7Jw8LCw4uH3sjS1YfC38bK18vCh87Uh8bJh9LJwcjV09LJxtPCh8jJwofByNWH3sjS1YfG1cDSysLJ04uFrdTGzsOH78jLysLUi4fTxszOycCH08/Ch9fG18LVh8bJw4fAy8bJxM7JwIfPztSHwt7Ch8PI0MmHztOJh4Xzz$

dekoodattu = xorstring(string, key, decode=True)

print dekoodattu
```

and run the script, the output is correct:

```
root@45s:~# python test.py 
"Indeed, your example is an unfortunate one for your argument,"
said Holmes, taking the paper and glancing his eye down it. "This
is the Dundas separation case, and, as it happens, I was engaged
in clearing up some small points in connection with it. The
husband was a teetotaler, there was no other woman, and the
conduct complained of was that he had drifted into the habit of
winding up every meal by taking out his false teeth and hurling
them at his wife, which, you will allow, is not an action likely
to occur to the imagination of the average story-teller. Take a
pinch of snuff, Doctor, and acknowledge that I have scored over
you in your example."61183668062528759535
```

I'm totally lost here that why is the script working on it's own but in the main script the decryption is mangled - i guess something is added or removed from either the key or string in some stage but can't figure out where or why.

Any help is extremely appreciated :)

Comment: I can't see any obvious bugs, so I suspect that there's something wrong with the key. Are you sure it's really just `\xa7`? What's the output of `print(repr(key))`?

Comment: In fact, it looks like your key is actually `"\\xa7"`, that is, it's a string that looks like a hex character sequence, not the single character `"\xa7"`.

Comment: Okay, this one was good advice, 

print key produces
[!] POSSIBLE KEY DETECTED BY XORTOOL: \xf6

print repr(key) produces
[+] GOT KEY: '\x1b[0;1;31m\\xf6\x1b[0m'

So i guess im missing something here:

    for line in lines:
        #to see output of xortool
        print "[+]" + line
        if "possible" in line:
            key = next(lines, '')
            print "[!] POSSIBLE KEY DETECTED BY XORTOOL: " + key

    return key

Is there any more approriate way to match next string after the line than im using here?

Comment: Well, there's your problem. The `xortool` program prints the key in red, using ANSI escape codes. You can either strip the ANSI stuff (`\x1b[0;1;31m` and `\x1b[0m`) manually or a find a way to tell `xortool` to output it without the color. But it _also_ prints the key as `\xf6` (that's a string with 4 characters, not a single character), so you have to use `'\\xf6'.decode('string-escape')` to turn it into a `\xf6` character.

Comment: Worked out beautifully - thank you so much!